# Changing a tab and clearing content

Tags: c#, tabs

I have a program which gives two options through which to test a student's knowledge of complex numbers. However, I want the content in the tab (labels, textboxes) to be cleared when the tab is changed. Is there a method I can use to do this?

Comment: Is it winforms? If yes, you can subscribe to IndexChanged event and in handler just set __textBlock1.Text = String.Empty__ . If this about wpf decision the same anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `TabControl` and retrieve all the controls within the tab. Now you can loop through controls and do whatever you want with them, like this-

```
    // SelectedIndexChange Event
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get Selected Tab
        var selectedTab = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        foreach (Control ctrl in selectedTab.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                (ctrl as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (ctrl is Label)
            {
                (ctrl as Label).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            // Other Controls....
        }
    }
```

hope it helps...!!

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the value of label and textbox in Tabchange event. Take a look at

[Tab Change MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage_events.aspx)

Hope it helps